How does Electrum ismine() work?
How does Electrum ismine() work?
All the help says is:

Check if address is in wallet. Return true if and only address is in wallet

Does ismine() check if an address could be derived from the master key, or does it simply check if it's in the list of already-derived addresses in the wallet?

As of 29a8c41025971140b0055b11fa8f86a4a3f81b17, when calling ismine, electrum will check:

If known derived addresses contain the target address
If addresses that have been imported into the wallet (typically, for non-hierarchical wallets) contain the target address

It will not attempt to search as-of-yet not in the database, but theoretically derivable addresses from the same seed.
Such a search would always be non-exhaustive. Given the potential combinations for derivation paths, and the ~4 billion addresses at each level, you can't really conclusively prove that an address is not in a given wallet. You could exhaustively search a single BIP32 account, but even that would be extremely slow given the sheer number of addresses you would have to derive. No wallet that I'm aware of does this.

"Given the potential combinations for derivation paths, and the ~4 billion addresses at each level, you can't really conclusively prove that an address is not in a given wallet." Yes, good point.
